# Custom normalization in Windows 7 Speech Recognition

Tags: windows-7, speech-recognition

I am using Windows 7 built in Speech Recognition to fill some forms. It works quite well but I have a problem. The speech recognizer does some kind of automatic normalization. For example, if I say "twelve dollars and fifty cents" it writes $12.5. That's good.

However, if I say "15 by 3 metres" it writes that phrase exactly and not what I would like it to write: "15x3 m".

How can I customize the speech normalization process to do what I need to?

Answer (score 0):

There is definitely no way to do this using the SAPI APIs.  (The [lexicon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms717899%28VS.85%29.aspx) APIs are close, but aren't parameterizable.)

The only way I know to customize the normalization entries would be to use the [Dictation Resource Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=b5920ef3-ff03-453f-902c-eae618987ff9&displaylang=en), but that's overkill for this purpose - you would have to rebuild the entire dictation grammar from scratch (since the DRK doesn't include the sources for the default dictation grammar).

Comment: Thanks for your answer Eric.

I have been doing some research and I think that if I invoke the speech engine from custom code I can add alternative grammars and use them along with the standard dictation grammar. Maybe I can write a SRGS grammar and use <tag> to normalize those expressions but I have to do some tests to be sure. 

Do you have some experience writing custom grammars? Do you think it will work?

Comment: Well, that depends.  If you are using your own recognizer inside the form application, then it's possible, but it can become difficult, particularly if you need correction.  But if you're trying to leverage WSR to add these behaviors to any application, then that's probably not possible - the dictation pipeline isn't available to grammars, and while you can use SendChars (or the like) to insert text into a document, you can't correct text inserted in that manner.

Answer (score 0):

you can disable it and implement your own speech-handler, look at this thread [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues/thread/f2f213d6-d801-49a1-b7dd-4139a357c517/)